# SPFX - SP.UI.Notifications.addNotifcation not available?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I've created a webpart using SPFX GA. In the externals section of the config.json I've added  the following from the layouts folder.

- init.js
- microsoftajax.js
- sp.runtime.js
- sp.js
- sp.ui.dialog.js

In the webparts.tsx they are added as Required('name').

However when trying to add a notification using `SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("message",false);`,  it says that SP.UI.Notify is undefined.

Is this not available in a SPFX webpart?

Answer (score 2):

The SP.UI namespace correspond to the classic SharePoint UI and, as far as I know, doesn't have an equivalent in modern sites. While you could theoretically load all scripts, required to use this namespace, the notification would not be shown on modern sites.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response Waldek. Any idea if there is a modern replacement for notifications? I haven't found it yet.

Comment: the fabric Message  class is kind of similar, you could try that

Comment: I haven't seen any documentation of it @user64939. It could be that it's still in making.